# Install Spring Samples in STS

Tags: java, spring

I'm using STS for Spring development and I want to import the projects located here https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/ into the IDE. I'm not for sure how to do that and I'm not familiar with SVN. Is SVN the only way to install these projects or is there a different/better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easiest way I know. Go to [svn](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html), download and install svn.

Create source directory => Right click on directory => click on SVN check out => Give Repository URL as https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/ => click OK

Your code will be downloaded. And most IMP, get familiar with Versioning tools like CVS, SVN.

Comment: +1, but: Forget CVS (at least if you don't know it yet). Get familiar with SVN and Git (and possibly others)

Comment: Yea, my goal this week is to get familiar with tortoise. Thanks for helping me and other out.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd : Actually I am familiar with svn(I use it) and cvs(little), so I suggested both. Thanks :)